# Microsoft Excel: Is there any way to copy multiple line items in one cell and paste these items in various cells/rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

Like for example this cell below:

[image]

I wanted these data or terms transferred or distributed to various rows as shown below:

[image]

I had tried copying these cells to unformatted text in word and copied it back to excel in unformatted text however the data is messed when I tried the method.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: "however the data is messed when I tried the method." - I suppose your data is more complicated then the example. Please include a more realistic example (also show how exactly it's messed up).

Comment: Put a comma between different Titles, use convert Text to columns (under Data Tab and use comma as delimiter), your data will become columns copy it and use paste special Transpose.

Answer (score 0):

With data in **A1**, in **A5** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A$1,CHAR(10),REPT(" ",999)),ROWS($1:1)*999-998,999))
```

and copy down:

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is great. I'll try this formula. Thanks Gary's Student.